# Nhibernate Linq & operator RegisterFunction Firebird

Tags: nhibernate, firebird, linq-to-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with Firebird and would like to create the bitwise and operator to the Firebird function `bin_and(a, b)`

Something like this:

```
var result = customers.Where(c => (c.StatusValue & 3) > 0);
```

The above query will result in something like that:

```
select * from customers where (StatusValue & 3) > 0
```

Which is not valid in Firebird, the result should be:

```
select * from customers where bin_and(StatusValue,3) > 0
```

Is there a possibility to overwrite this translated result ?

**Update**

By declaring a function this is possible:

> ```
>   [LinqExtensionMethod("BIN_AND")]
>   public static int BinAnd(int a, int b)
>   {
>      return a & b;
>   }
> ```
>
> `var result = customers.Where(c => BinAnd(c.StatusValue, 3) > 0);`

This works, but I am searching for a more generic way wizh the '&' or '|' operator...

**Update:**

@ Fédéric:

I wrote my own Dialect class like this:

```
 public class MyFirebirdDialect: FirebirdDialect    {
       public MyFirebirdDialect()
       {
          // Bitwise operations
          RegisterFunction("band", new BitwiseFunctionOperation("bin_and"));
          RegisterFunction("bor", new BitwiseFunctionOperation("bin_or"));
          RegisterFunction("bxor", new BitwiseFunctionOperation("bin_xor"));
          RegisterFunction("bnot", new BitwiseFunctionOperation("bin_not"));
       }    
}
```

I had to import the BitwiseFunctionOperation.cs too

If I debug the code I see that this class is used as Dialect, and I see that there is a custom function for the key 'band' that has a value 'bin_and' but a Query like this

```
 var result = customers.Where(c => (c.StatusValue & 3) > 0);
```

ends up in an sql like this :

```
 select * from customers where (StatusValue & 3) > 0
```

I think the linq parser does not its part...

Comment: All the required Linq code seem to be there since NHibernate v3.0 in the built-in Linq provider. Have you checked with a [tag:hql] query using HQL `band()` that it was generating the adequate SQL?

Comment: I will check this tomorrow and give response

Comment: Ok I downloaded the source code and the 'HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor' is never called. The hql command does neither work, it is always used the '&' in my sql...

Comment: Well, the ability to redefine bitwise operations as functions appears to have been [added](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/0a09056ec8482158eae8c88fa934a2ebbbee0159#diff-afa763d1aac6c55614381a3547487228) in NHibernate 4.1 too. That is why the HQL does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the appropriate dialect? `FirebirdDialect` correctly defines bitwise and in HQL ([`RegisterFunction("band", new BitwiseFunctionOperation("bin_and"));`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/FirebirdDialect.cs#L325) and [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) translate `&` (`ExpressionType.And`) to the [appropriate HQL call](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.cs#L273).

If you are using an old NHibernate version, maybe you need to upgrade.

Firebird bitwise operators have been added with [NH-3630](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3630) in NHibernate 4.1.

You may try to back-port them in your project by using a custom dialect deriving from `FirebirdDialect` and registering those additional functions as illustrated in the link above, within your custom dialect constructor.

But that will not work, because it requires some other [changes](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/0a09056ec8482158eae8c88fa934a2ebbbee0159#diff-afa763d1aac6c55614381a3547487228) in NHibernate internals, not available before NHibernate 4.1. Maybe by patching a local copy of NHibernate 3.4 sources may you succeed in doing that.

Comment: Ahh Frédéric, what a suprise :-) I am using Nhibernate 3.4, that's the last version that supports .Net 3.5. The result of customers.Where(c => (c.StatusValue & 3) > 0) does not transform in the desired 'bin_and'

Comment: See my edit. Of course it would be better to upgrade your application framework. 3.5 is nearing its end of support.